# UiWatcher not working(not even called)

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I could not get the UiWatcher to work in my code, it does not ever seem to be called even when the UiSelector does not match anything.

```
public void runWirelessWatcher() throws UiObjectNotFoundException { 


        String NONETWORKWATCHER_STRING = "CancelWirelessWatcher";
        UiWatcher CancelWirelessWatcher= new UiWatcher() {
            @Override
            public boolean checkForCondition() {
                UiObject okDialog = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("No Network"));
                if(okDialog.exists()){

                    UiObject okButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Home"));
                    try {
                        okButton.click();
                    } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return (okDialog.waitUntilGone(25000));
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        UiDevice.getInstance().registerWatcher(NONETWORKWATCHER_STRING, CancelWirelessWatcher);
        UiDevice.getInstance().runWatchers();
    }
```

Here is my code:

```
  getUiDevice().pressHome();
  UiObject allAppsButton = new UiObject(new   UiSelector().description("Apps"));
  allAppsButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
  UiObject playstoretab = new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("PlayStore"));
  playstoretab.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
```

Here when the wireless not connected error appears with "Home" button, Uiwatcher fails to click the home button.(Uiwatcher not even called)

Comment: Are you sure it is not being called? Have you tried putting in a log to see if the dialog ever exists?

Comment: I've given a message to print(before "String NONETWORK..") to make sure it is being called.However even the message is not printed...it means..it is not being called.

Comment: And just another note, If you are expecting the watcher to be the last thing in your code, it wont work. The way the watchers work is they only are running while your test are running. The test won't "wait" for the watcher to execute.

Comment: Where you return false in your watcher, add the line `Log.d("WATCHER", "Watcher is running");`. That way we can really see.

Comment: In your code, your not calling the `runWirelessWatcher();` method

Comment: After the playstore, i've a set of code to be executed.                                     As soon as the Wireless message appears with "home" button after playstore is clicked, Watcher will become alive and press the home button ?   Am i missing something here?

Comment: Well first I would start your watcher at the beginning of your test. You don't need to register your watcher when you are expecting it to return true. The way the watcher work, is if there is no option (or the test is about to fail) it tries all the watchers you have running. So if you watcher is that last command in your test, the watcher will not return true. So to fix this, be sure that your watcher command is *not* the last command in your test. Add something after it that will be in the next activity after the watcher command is called. Does this make sense?

Comment: This wont fix your code, but remove the `throws UiObjectNotFoundException` from your method body. You already have a try/catch. no need for both

Comment: See my edit. It might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `runWirelessWatcher();` to your code.

```
  runWirelessWatcher();
  getUiDevice().pressHome();
  UiObject allAppsButton = new UiObject(new   UiSelector().description("Apps"));
  allAppsButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
  UiObject playstoretab = new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("PlayStore"));
  playstoretab.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
```

Unless you are already doing this and you aren't showing it.

### Edit

**Try this: it will help debug:** (Just copy/paste)

```
 public void runWirelessWatcher() throws UiObjectNotFoundException { 


    String NONETWORKWATCHER_STRING = "CancelWirelessWatcher";
    UiWatcher CancelWirelessWatcher= new UiWatcher() {
        @Override
        public boolean checkForCondition() {
            UiObject okDialog = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("No Network"));
            if(okDialog.exists()){

                UiObject okButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Home"));
                try {
                    okButton.click();
                } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("Watcher", "Found okButton!");
                return (true);
            }
            Log.d("watcher", "Watcher is running");
            return false;
        }
    };
    UiDevice.getInstance().registerWatcher(NONETWORKWATCHER_STRING, CancelWirelessWatcher);

}
```

**And your code:**

```
runWirelessWatcher();
UiDevice.getInstance.runWatchers();
getUiDevice().pressHome();
UiObject allAppsButton = new UiObject(new   UiSelector().description("Apps"));
allAppsButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
UiObject playstoretab = new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("PlayStore"));
playstoretab.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
//this is where your watcher should be called? 
//Do something here to keep test running
```

Comment: It's working fine, I've added runWirelessWatcher();
UiDevice.getInstance.runWatchers(); in the code as you mentioned.As soon as the wireless overlay appears, watcher is invoked and pressed home.